# Generating Excel report from different databases

Tags: database, excel

I'm not sure how this can be done, so I'll try to explain what I need to do.

All data from the excel sheets will be imported into a database hourly. There are 10 different locations that will be adding data in 10 databases every hour. How can be exported in excel report collected from all 10 locations. All 10 are working with Windows Server 2003 if that helps.
Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to combine the data together? If so - you would be much better to use SSIS + SSRS, both supplied with SQL Server package.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need, to combine the data. Thank you for the reply!